# How to hide div when it's already open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I couldn't think of any better title, so I  will try to explain my question here as clear as possible. I'm quite a newbie in JQuery so this is probably a very easy question.

I have some divs with a button on it. When you click the button, another div should pop-up.
My question is: How can I make the div, which is already open, close when clicking on another button?

I made a fiddle with some example code: http://jsfiddle.net/zuvjx775/1/

And the example code here:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="test">
        <input type='button' class='showDiv' id="1" value='click!' />    
    </div>
    <div class="show_1">

    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="test">
        <input type='button' class='showDiv' id="2"value='click!' /> 
    </div>
    <div class="show_2">

    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.showDiv').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.show_'+id).show();
});
```

When `show_1` for example is visible, and I click on the button in div2, I want `show_2` to come up, which it does, but `show_1` to dissapear.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: note that beginning an id with a number (such as `id="1"`) is considered "bad practice" in HTML5 and is actually *invalid* in previous specifications of HTML. See [this definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) of the id attribute for HTML 4, and [this definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) for HTML 5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can hide all divs that their class starts with 'show' before show the one you want. For example:

```js
$('.showDiv').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $("div[class^='show']").hide();//find div class starts with 'show' and hide them
  $('.show_' + id).show();
});
```

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
}
.show_1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
.show_2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
.wrapper {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test">
    <input type='button' class='showDiv' id="1" value='click!' />
  </div>
  <div class="show_1">

  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test">
    <input type='button' class='showDiv' id="2" value='click!' />
  </div>
  <div class="show_2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even thought this was actually possible! :D

Answer (score 1):

Is the structure of the document fixed?
is so... I guess the easiest way of doing this is to just do the following:

```js
$('.showDiv').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id == 1){
      $('.show_1').show();
      $('.show_2').hide();
    }else{
      $('.show_2').show();
      $('.show_1').hide();
    }        
})
```

Comment: In my actual code this is not an option, since I have over 50 divs which are dynamically generated, but maybe this will be an option to someone else :)